# Detecting selected item in the object inspectors collection editor

Tags: delphi

I'm developing a component which contains a property derived from TOwnedCollection. At design time, when the user selects a collection item in the object inspector, I'd like to know which one it is in order to paint the component with some feedback info.

I have looked at the Notify method, but that doesn't respond to selection changes. Neither does TCollection contain something like ItemIndex, which would have been helpful. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Best regards
Oivnd

Comment: Long story short: Roll out your own collection editor. I wanted similar customization once, but it's just not an option.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. I feared this. Creating a component editor for solving quite a small problem is however a waste of time. Better find a workaround.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690395/how-to-add-icons-to-the-standard-collection-editor One comment suggests locating the source of the original collection editor, which I never actually did myself.